# What is $\int \frac{x^4}{(a^2+x^2)^4}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus

What is $\int \frac{x^4}{(a^2+x^2)^4}\,dx$?

I think partial fraction is to be used but couldn't figure out the rest. I'm probably missing some concept.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%28x%2F%28x%5E2%2Ba%5E2%29%29%5E4&t=crmtb01

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Use partial fractions and substitute $\text{u}=\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\text{a}}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, without any loss taking take $a=1$ and substitute $x=\text{tan}z$.
So, the integral becomes

$\int \frac{\text{tan}^4z}{\text{sec}^6z} dz$

$=\int \frac{(\text{sec}^2z-1)^2}{\text{sec}^6z} dz$

$=\int (\text{cos}^2z -2\text{cos}^4z+\text{cos}^6z )dz$